# How to use the same singleton instance in Razor pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, dependency-injection, singleton

I'm writing an ASP.NET Core app and ran into the peculiar problem that my Razor pages seem to use different singleton instances than the rest of the app.

The problem manifests itself by showing no items in a `List` property of the service being empty in Razor pages even when items have been added by page handlers.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<MyContext>();
    services.AddSingleton<MyService>(new MyService());

    services.AddRazorPages();
}
```

```
public class MyService
{
    public int[] Items { get { return this.items.ToArray(); } }

    private List<int> items = new List<int>();

    public MyService() {}

    public void Add(int i) => this.items.Add(i);
}
```

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAddAsync(MyService myService)
{
    myService.Add(1);
}
```

```
@page
@inject MyService myService
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

<a asp-page-handler="Add">Add</a>
<p>
    @myService.Items.Count() - always 0
</p>
```

Debugging also shows the private List to have no items in Razor pages even when it does elsewhere.

---

From my understanding singletons should only have one instance, not several.

I tried implementing a singleton pattern with a private constructor, a static instance-getter, and the service added as `AddSingleton<MyService>(f => MyService.GetInstance())`, but that ran into an exception about dependency injection not being able to create an instance.

> Model bound complex types must not be abstract or value types and must have a parameterless constructor.

---

What am I doing wrong? How do I get Razor pages to use the same singleton instance?

Comment: The only way the count will go up is if you call `Add` method and then the code in razor is executed after. Plus it must be done within the same request. Put a breakpoint and debug and see if that's happening.

Comment: @CodingYoshi I thought singletons survived multiple requests?

Comment: Why are you saying singleton, what makes you think you have a singleton? Is it `services.AddSingleton<MyService>`? I haven't used that. If that works the way a singleton would work, then the count will go up if `Add` is called and razor page is executed after each call to `Add`.

Comment: @CodingYoshi https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1#singleton sounds like `AddSingleton<T>(T)` does what I want, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes. My previous comment still applies.

Comment: @CodingYoshi Well, the count in the Razor page stays 0 even if I refresh the page in the browser, or do Razor pages get cached app-side somehow?

Comment: Have you confirmed if `Add` is ever called? That's the only thing you need to confirm.

Comment: @CodingYoshi Yes, I just tried it again. Add is definitely called and an item is definitely added. But the Razor page doesn't see it.

Comment: I think in this code `myService.Add(1)`, `myService` is a brand new instance of `MyService` which is created on each request. I could be wrong so you can test. To test, before registering your singleton instance do this: `var singleton = new MyService(); singleton.Add(-1); services.AddSingleton<MyService>(singleton)`. Then razor should show this one item but in `myService.Add(1)`, there would be no items. That will confirm its not the same instance.

Comment: @CodingYoshi You are right, actually. The Razor page uses the instance created during `ConfigureServices`, `OnPostAddAsync` does not.

Comment: Create an interface for your service. Then register the interface as a singleton. In your controller's constructor,  the framework will always inject the same instance and you can use that one. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1) for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to inject the service in the `IndexModel` constructor and not as a parameter to the page handler method.

```
private readonly MyService _myService;

public IndexModel(MyService myService)
{
    _myService = myService;
}

public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAddAsync()
{
    _myService.Add(1);
}
```